# How to properly handle filenames in argv

Tags: c++, encoding, character-encoding, cross-platform

For example, if my Windows uses Simplified Chinese GB18030 encoding, argv is GB18030 encoded, but if the filename contains a Greek word like `Ελληνική γλώσσα`, it leads to a strange result that the file is successfully opened but no changes can be made, while my Linux uses UTF-8 encoding which does not have this problem.

So how should I solve such a problem?

---

**Update:**

For example, code like:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  std::ofstream(argv[1]);
  f << argv[2];
}
```

Compile it under msys2/mingw64 and run:

```bash
./test 'Ελληνική γλώσσα.txt' 'foobar'
```

The program runs in its entirety and reports no errors, but:

```bash
cat 'Ελληνική γλώσσα.txt'
```

Show that this is an empty file, It doesn't show anything also when opened with notepad3.

I know I can get it to work with something like `wmain`, `CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), ...)`, but they are Windows platform specific, I'm curious if there's a more cross-platform way to make this work?

Comment: If you open a file using a mode that allows modification, it's very odd that the file can be opened successfully but not written to. Please try to create a [mre] to show us what you're doing. And please include some error checking for your modification operations to report errors writing to the file, and what the error might be.

Comment: Consider doing this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=msvc-170

Comment: `wmain` is definitely the required approach, you might want to convert to utf-8 and convert back to wchar when opening files http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @AlanBirtles: `utf-8` is a fairly weird suggestion for Windows. The issue here is that the API is natively UTF-16, both the file API and the command-line API. `<filesystem>` can handle the UTF-16, and `wmain` provides you with that UTF-16, so why convert in the middle?

Comment: @MSalters "Everywhere" is a term that includes Windows i presume. Also, if the program should work on non-windows systems, it might be a good idea to use an intermediate representation of the data which does not depend on Windows.

Comment: @Mestkon: That manifesto (and its URL) predate `<filesystem>`. This is important for two reasons: the manifesto couldn't consider `<filesystem>`, but the rationale for `<filesystem>` did consider UTF-8. Still, the designers of C++ including Microsoft consider `std::filesystem::path` to be a better datatype for filesystem paths.

Comment: @MSalters If `c++17` is available and heap allocation can be used then `std::filesystem::path` is indeed a usable intermediate representation which does not depend on Windows.

Comment: @MSalters yes, utf-8 is not the best for windows on it's own but if you have an existing cross platform codebase using `char`/`std::string` then making all of that just hold `utf-8` and convert to `wchar_t` when interacting with the windows API will be a much smaller change than having to have different string types on different platforms